# Authentication in ASP.NET Core API WebService using Active Directory

Tags: api, web-services, asp.net-core

I'd like to offer a WebService API to a set of intranet desktop applications.

Currently my web service configuration (launchSettings.json) is:

```
"windowsAuthentication": true, 
"anonymousAuthentication": false
```

This approach needs this line of code at the Startup class:

```
services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
```

When I test it the browser (Firefox in my case) calls the default controller. Then I get a prompt asking the user and password from the active directory user, which is already logged in. After a successful log-in I can see the user name and its status within my controller class:

```
var isAuthenticated = User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
var userName = User.Identity.Name;
```

But as already noted: the current user it's already logged in into this Windows machine so, could I forward this information in order to avoid this log in prompt?

At test stages is not a big problem to enter this information, but I guess when other kind of clients (my custom desktop applications) try to use this WebServices they will need to also call the WebServices in such a way that the user gets authorized.

Please, consider I am getting started with the asp.net, core and webservices technologies, so if you need more information, let me know :D

Answer (score 0):

Firefox doesn't support automatic login. Only Chrome and IE/Edge do.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Chris but as you may have read I don't mind if the debug situation is like it is, but what about if I write a desktop application? How does this login information is passed/exchanged?